# if else in map function in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Scala and spark,  I have tried below code but it is not working. Can anyone help me (in Scala only not Data-frames) to solve it. After this I have to do a few more transformations

Code :

```
val file = sc.textFile("winners.csv")
file.map(_.split(",")).map{x=>if(x(0)==x(2)) x(1) else if(x(1)==x(2)) x(0), x(2)}
```

**Input**:
Team_1, Team_2 ,**winner**

Team_A, Team_B, Team_B

Team_C, Team_D, Team_C

Team_B, Team_C, Team_B

Team_A, Team_D, Team_A

Team_D, Team_B, **Tie**

**Output**:

Looser, Winner

Team_A, Team_B

Team_D, Team_C

Team_C, Team_B

Team_D, Team_A

Tied match is not required

Comment: What problem do you have with your solution?

Comment: the code is not working. you can try your own way but want mentioned output(in scala only not DF)

Comment: Not working how? Is it wrong output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`If`'s are messy, use match whenever possible:

```
   file.map(_.split(",")).collect {
      case Array(a, b, c) if a == c => s"$b,$c"
      case Array(a, b, c) if b == c => s"$a,$c"
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Assuming `textFile` reads the lines to a Seq[String]
val file = sc.textFile("winners.csv")
file
  .tail
  .map(_.split(","))
  .filter(_(2) != "Tied")
  .map(x => if (x(0) == x(2)) s"${x(1)},${x(0)}" else s"${x(0)},${x(1)}")
```

Comment: Need winner column too in output

Comment: Here 'textFile' reading data as Array[String], so this is not working

Comment: `Array[String]` _is a_ `Seq[String]`, so I would expect this to work (see https://alvinalexander.com/scala/understanding-scala-collections-hierarchy-cookbook). Care to elaborate on "this is not working"? What error message are you getting?

Comment: Output is as below : 
${x(1)},${x(0)}
${x(1)},${x(0)}
${x(0)},${x(1)}

Comment: After adding s, its working now. thanks for your time. s"${x(1)},${x(0)}"

Comment: Ah yeah typo :)